# Why is only the first question printed in my quiz and nothing else?

Tags: python

I'm writing a quiz program. However, only the first question is printing. Not even the first sentence.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import math
import string
import random

print("Simple Star Wars quiz. (SPOILERS!!!) Made by Andy Chakarov.")
cor1 = "Anakin Skywalker" #What other name does Darth Vader go by? (hint: he said that it doesnt mean anything to him anymore in episode 6 Return of the Jedi)
cor2 = "Ben Solo" #What was the original name of Kylo Ren?
cor3 = "Death Star" #What was the ultimate weapon that was rebuilt 3 times
wrong = 0


g1 = input("What other name does Darth Vader go by? (hint: he said that it doesnt mean anything to him anymore in episode 6 Return of the Jedi): ")
if g1 == cor1:
     print("Congratulations! You got the answer right!")
else:
    print("That's not true!")
    wrong + 1

g2 = input("What was the original name of Kylo Ren?: ")
if g2 == cor2:
     print("Congratulations! You got the answer right!")
else:
    print("That's not true!")
    wrong + 1

g3 = input("What was the ultimate weapon that was rebuilt 3 times?: ")
if g3 == cor3:
    print("Congratulations! You got the answer right!")
else:
    print("That's not true!")
    wrong + 1

print("The quiz is over! You got", wrong, "answers out of 3!")
```

Comment: You should use ``wrong += 1``.

Comment: I sympathise with asking "dumb questions" when you're completely stuck and have at least made an effort, though you do really need to tell people _why_ it's not working next time.  (in this case, I reckon the first comment is probably what you were after)

Comment: *I did everything I had to do but the code still didnt work.* - What is *everything*? And what exactly does *code still didnt work* mean? 20 Errors? Blank screen, stackoverflow, blue screen....?  Please describe exactly what you did, what you expected to happen and what actually happens. Please read [ask]

Comment: @mkreiger1 no but even the first sentence isnt printing. Only the first question is printing.

Comment: Only the first QUESTION is printing. Not even the first sentence.

Comment: I suggest reducing the code to a minimal version which still shows a problem. This will make the question clearer. You can [edit] your question to clarify it. By the way, doing that could help you find the problem by yourself, without any help. See [mcve].

Comment: So your minimum reproducible example should involve an input statement and then print out what was input? Is the user hitting the enter key? Are you running in git bash on windows?

Comment: Check if you have a valid Python interpreter. Can you paste the error you see?

Comment: I have no idea what error you are encountering, I run the whole python script and it seems to run well("wrong" not working ofc), I think you might've not saved the file before re-running, or your python interpreter is somehow not working correctly??

Comment: Post a screenshot of the code interpreter or the terminal output

Comment: Hi there. We don't use `[Solved]` title hacks here. Please either accept an answer below (by ticking it) or write a self-answer and accept/tick that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works.
Just that you get a 0 score even if you answer all the questions right.
Thats because you've specified `wrong` in the final result.

```
Simple Star Wars quiz. (SPOILERS!!!) Made by Andy Chakarov.
What other name does Darth Vader go by? (hint: he said that it doesnt mean anything to him anymore in episode 6 Return of the Jedi): Anakin Skywalker
Congratulations! You got the answer right!
What was the original name of Kylo Ren?: Ben Solo
Congratulations! You got the answer right!
What was the ultimate weapon that was rebuilt 3 times?: Death Star
Congratulations! You got the answer right!
The quiz is over! You got 0 answers out of 3!
```

And regarding it only printing the 1st sentence..I wonder what tool/IDE you're using to run this? You're probably not seeing an option to enter the input values. Better try running it on something like a Jupyter notebook for example and you can see that option